# Paypal REST API Adaptive / Multiple Payments (change payee)

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I've just started looking at Paypal's [REST api](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/). One thing I can't seem to see is a feature paypal call [Adaptive Payments](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/adaptive-payments/gs_AdaptivePayments). This allows me to register my app with my developer account, but not be involved in the actual payments. e.g. my app allows my users to accept payment for their services, which they sell through my app.

I have been through Paypals REST API documents. I have worked out how to complete a payment, but all the transactions get sent through to my developer paypal account. I can't find where i would change the receiver details, i.e. the seller, to allow payments to be sent to a different paypal account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of January 3rd 2017, PayPal has now added the ability to set the payee to anyone you wish.

Notice the new `payee` object below:

```
{
    'intent':'sale',
    'redirect_urls':{
        'return_url':'http://localhost:3000/process',
        'cancel_url':'http://localhost:3000/cancel'
    },
    'payer':{
        'payment_method':'paypal'
    },
    'transactions':[{
        'amount':{
            'total':'10',
            'currency':'USD'
        },
        'payee':{
            'email': 'payee@test.com'
        },
        'description':'My amazing product'
    }]
}
```

However, there doesn't seem to be an ability to have multiple payee's.

Additional info here: https://devblog.paypal.com/setting-payee/

Answer (score 23):

Ok, after some extensive googling, I managed to find the answer [here](http://whyidentity.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/under-hood-restful-payments-api.html)

> This general model enables us to easily add support for variety of payment models in the future (Parallel, Chained, etc). The Payee could be a funding instrument (like a Credit/Debit Card,) or a PayPal account (wallet) itself. The Payee could be set explicitly if the Payee is not the same as the Payment Facilitator ( in this current release we only support the case where the Payee is same as the Facilitator) so this is not currently required.

So looks like a payee is just added to the transactions array, but this is not currently implemented as of the date of this answer.

Comment: thanks Praveen. Any ideas roughly when these new cases will be added? I am just starting out with Paypal API and would like to avoid learning the classic API if new functions are coming soon to the REST API

Comment: No ETA yet - as you can imagine PayPal classic APIs support tons of payment features and it would take us some time to catch up with those . We are trying to prioritize on the popularity of the use case as requested by the developer community. I will pass this on to our product folks so they can prioritize as appropriate.

Comment: Hi Praveen - any news on this?

Comment: Sorry Gaz_Edge - still the same status. We just released the global support in the REST APIs and working on some foundations for parallel payments but definitely a long way to go.

Comment: Hello @Praveen ! Any news now or we still have to use for topicstarter case only classic API?

Comment: @Praveen - any updates? I didn't realise you were moving away from the Adaptive system (I've just started coding my site with it, as I need parallel payments).

Comment: sorry folks I don't work for PayPal anymore - can you please contact PayPal developer support - not sure if they are actively monitoring stackoverflow or not: https://paypal.com/dts

Comment: Does anyone know if this functionality is available yet? (Payer make payment to Payee (who's not the fascilitator))

Comment: Is there a difference if adding the payee / merchant as header `PayPal-Auth-Assertion`? Both seem to work now but just adding the payee to the transaction object is easier.