# Paypal REST API: Fee not returned in Details object

Tags: paypal

The "common objects" section in the documentation lists the fee being returned by the API in the payment response. However, it says *optional*, and in my tests (using production credentials), the fees aren't being returned. Is there a parameter I need to be passing along to force it to be returned?

Comment: I documented the problem and a temporary solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347904/paypal-rest-api-bug-fee-charged-by-paypal-not-set-in-response

Comment: I've also documented there is no Fraud Detection support in the REST API. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16490579/paypal-rest-api-no-fraud-protection-available . Developer.paypal.com has some work to do.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15405632/paypal-rest-api-adaptive-multiple-payments-change-payee