# Paypal REST API Bug - Fee Charged By PayPal NOT SET in Response

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

## UPDATE: Issue applies to both TEST and LIVE API Requests

At first I thought this was a Test Environment bug but I've confirms it applies to production as well. It's critical to know `Fees Charged By PayPal`.

---

**Is there a way to get the Paypal Test environment ([developer.paypal.com](http://developer.paypal.com)) to respond with fees charged by PayPal?**  *Neither a `Sale` or a `Sale Lookup` seem to return the `Paypal Fee` seen in live transactions.* Are we forced to test with live transactions (not a best practice)? Without the same fee values you see in the live environment, its hard to unit test our accounting system in development.

### Request - Credit Card Charge ($43) with Stored Card

```
        $cardToken = new CreditCardToken();
        $cardToken->setCredit_card_id( $cc->getRefid() );

        $fi = new FundingInstrument();
        $fi->setCredit_card_token( $cardToken );

        $payer = new Payer();
        $payer->setPayment_method('credit_card');
        $payer->setFunding_instruments(array($fi));

        $amount = new Amount();
        $amount->setCurrency('USD');
        $amount->setTotal('43.00');

        $transaction = new Transaction();
        $transaction->setAmount($amount);
        $transaction->setDescription($note);

        $payment = new Payment();
        $payment->setIntent('sale');
        $payment->setPayer($payer);
        $payment->setTransactions(array($transaction));

        $response = $payment->create();
```

### Response - Approved ([full response](http://pastebin.com/UvinBGuc))

```
PayPal\Api\Transaction Object
                        (
                            [_propMap:PPModel:private] => Array
                                (
                                    [amount] => PayPal\Api\Amount Object
                                        (
                                            [_propMap:PPModel:private] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [total] => 43.00
                                                    [currency] => USD
                                                    [details] => PayPal\Api\AmountDetails Object
                                                        (
                                                            [_propMap:PPModel:private] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [subtotal] => 43.00
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )
```

### Documentation - `Fee Charged By PayPal`

**(Below Image)** - details object [from the documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#details-object) showing a `(string) fee charged by PayPal` - Which doesn't seem to expose itself in the test environment.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide an example where it was not returned?

Comment: I'll post the exact Request and Responses when I can, but essentially, using any of the SALE or Lookup examples on developer.paypal.com will return approved status and show an amount charged but won't reference Fees Charged by Paypal. In fact, none of the example responses in the developer area return a Fee Charged By Paypal. It's important to see these fees in the development environment because they exist when you make live requests.

Comment: I added an example where the `fee charged by PayPal` is not returned. The fee does not show up when you do a transaction look-up either.

Comment: This bug was fixed 2 days ago - https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Ruby-SDK/issues/14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the NVP API (GetTransactionDetails request) to return more accurate details in place of or along side the standard REST Responses. If you're interested I can post a PHP Example.

The REST API allows you to do things like manage a Credit Card vault.. so you can store a card and charge a card with the REST .. but when I charge it, I return the NVP API GetTransactionDetails response which includes `Fees Charged By Paypal` and everything else you need to know about the transaction that was charged via REST. It maybe be a hack and involve an extra API call but it works really well.

Comment: Is it still an issue and there is no way to retrieve fee via REST API?

Answer (score 0):

This is now available on the REST api. [Specifically, via the `transaction_fee` on the sale object.](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#sale_get_response)

You can also access `transaction_fee` from a payment object by drilling down. Here's a (slightly redacted) example response:

```
{
  "id": "PAY-5YK922393D847794YKER7MUI",
  "state": "approved",
  "intent": "sale",
  "payer": {...},
  "transactions": [
    {
      "related_resources": [
        {
          "sale": {
            "id": "36C38912MN9658832",
            "state": "completed",
            "amount": {
              "total": "7.47",
              "currency": "USD"
            },
            "transaction_fee": {
              "value": "1.75",
              "currency": "USD"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

For those following along at home, you can get the value of the transaction fee on this payment with the following simple and intuitive line of code:

```
payment.transactions[0].related_resources[0].sale.transaction_fee.value
```

See? Easy. Oh, but just remember - the sale object will not exist until *after* the payment has been executed.

Here's a [massive ticket on the Ruby SDK about how this feature was added](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Ruby-SDK/issues/14), if you want some light reading.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like it's known bug that will be fixed. Don't have the date yet.

Comment: Dennis, do you have a URL where we can locate bug tracking on this issue so more of us can follow it?

Comment: Dennis, just did a Live Transaction test for $1. The response contains NO information about the $.33 in fees this transaction incurred. I'd say this is pretty big oversight. I'd like to know where it's documented for the correct answer.

Comment: I found no documentation of this being an official bug.

Comment: Justin, I am checking to see when this bug will be fixed.

Comment: You can't just say "it's a known bug" and then not post a link to the issue tracker. :-p