# Paypal Rest API : Getting Fraud Protection

Tags: paypal

Does the Paypal REST API have any sort of Fraud Protection? I've run trial transactions in `Production` mode all day trying to get the REST API calls to detect and refuse a charge when the Security Code is wrong, Address mismatched -- but it charges them all regardless of my fraud filter settings. This is really risky behavior for a production environment.

Answer (score 1):

The primary benefit to using the rest api is to take advantage of its vault. Prior to storing a card, you could authorize it, **get the fraud filters**, and cancel the auth. Yes, this is another scenario with a redundant paypal api call but having fraud detection is critical and i can't imagine charging cards without it.