# Setting username, password and signature in Paypal REST api

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm somewhat familiar with the classic Paypal API but I'm trying to figure out a few things for the REST API. I browsed around the documentation but I couldn't find anything

1. With the REST API, Can I set a username, password and signature of the person to transfer the funds to just like I can with the classic API, or is it based entirely on the client_id and secret?
2. The software I'm working with is sort of like a marketplace where there are buyers and sellers. If I cannot use the username, password and signature for the individual sellers, is there some other way to handle the payments between buyers and sellers so that the sellers don't have to sign up for developer accounts to get their own client_id and secret?
3. Considering that credit cards are a form of payment, I assume this means I don't have to re-direct to Paypal's site to handle this, unlike the classic API. Correct?

I saw [this code](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/) sames for PHP on paypal's site, but I'm wondering if there are more in depth examples. Does anyone know of a good tutorial for the paypal REST API?

**For those of you downvoting, can you please point out anywhere in the documentation that it explicity answers my questions?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The PayPal REST API uses only OAuth 2.0 for authentication, so yes you need to provide a client id and secret, and call the OAuth end point to retrieve an access token to use in subsequent calls.
2. Currently there is no way to do that through the REST API.
3. Correct, the REST API does not require a redirect for the credit card use case.

With respect to samples, there are SDKs for several different languages, that include sample applications.  Is there something in particular that you are looking for?

Comment: thanks for the help. It doesn't seem like this will work for me. I did some more searching and I think I'll go through a service like [balanced](https://docs.balancedpayments.com/current/overview#use-cases). Of course I can search around and probably find some others, but from your experience do you happen to know of any quality services like this? Thanks again.

Comment: You could use the PayPal Adaptive Payments API it was explicitly built for the use cases you described.

Comment: yes, but that's not for the REST API if I understand correctly, as stated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15405632/paypal-rest-api-adaptive-multiple-payments)