# PayPal REST API Payment payee

Tags: php, api, rest, paypal

With the REST API and creating a payment, can you specify the payee?  For example, I'm going to be storing credit cards in the vault and the user will click a button to charge all of the users that have the highest price.  How do I send this money to his paypal account vs the business paypal account?  Please let me know and thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15405632/paypal-rest-api-adaptive-multiple-payments/15406377#15406377

Answer (score 2):

As of January 3rd 2017, the REST API now has the ability to set the payee to anyone you wish.

Notice the new `payee` object below:

```
{
    'intent':'sale',
    'redirect_urls':{
        'return_url':'http://localhost:3000/process',
        'cancel_url':'http://localhost:3000/cancel'
    },
    'payer':{
        'payment_method':'paypal'
    },
    'transactions':[{
        'amount':{
            'total':'10',
            'currency':'USD'
        },
        'payee':{
            'email': 'payee@test.com'
        },
        'description':'My amazing product'
    }]
}
```

Additional info here: https://devblog.paypal.com/setting-payee/

Comment: Is there any way to include a message to the payee? If you execute a payment normally (without the API) just via the console, then you can include a free text message when you send a payment. Is there any way to do the same thing via the API? I.e. Send a message to the payee with the payment.

Answer (score 1):

Not yet - the APIs do not support setting a Payee in the API calls. The APi caller is assumed to be the Payee. This is something that is still in works and hopefully we will have it out soon.

Comment: Hi Praveen, any updates on this? I'm outside US and am looking to accomplish something similar. Please have a look at this SO question as well: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19367125/1349295.