# PayPal mass payment with REST API

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, paypal

Is there a way to execute a mass payment from the application to several other accounts by e-mail addresses using the new REST API? I can do this with Classic API, but am not sure how to achieve the same with REST API.

I am working with PayPal SDK for C#.

I have found this related post: [Paypal REST API Adaptive / Multiple Payments (change payee)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15405632/paypal-rest-api-adaptive-multiple-payments). However, some code samples would be nice.

Comment: Paypal implemented REST only recently. It only supports a subset of what Classic encompasses. This can only be done in Classic, sadly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The PayPal C# SDK does not currently allow making these calls (11.11.2013.). The API itself has the functionality that allows setting the payee for the payment, however this functionality is still incomplete as the PayPal REST API is in beta.

Usage of PayPal Classic API is advised here as it is stable and tested.

Answer (score 4):

PayPal just made a REST version of Payouts available. [Here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payouts-overview/) is the Payouts Overview.

To get access:

- Go to your dashboard.
- Go to *My account*.
- Find the *Payouts capability* and click *Get Started*.

Answer (score 1):

This is Jason, the developer of the [**PayPal .NET SDK**](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK) on GitHub. [**Payouts API**](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#payouts) support (formerly known as Mass Payments) is now available in version **1.2** of the PayPal .NET SDK.  You can get the SDK binaries by downloading them directly from [GitHub](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/releases/tag/v1.2.0) or using [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PayPal).

There's also a [**Samples project**](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/tree/master/Samples) included with the SDK on GitHub that shows how to [create batch payouts](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/blob/v1.2.0/Samples/Source/PayoutCreate.aspx.cs) as well as [retrieve the details of a batch payout](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/blob/v1.2.0/Samples/Source/PayoutGet.aspx.cs) or [individual payout item](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/blob/v1.2.0/Samples/Source/PayoutItemGet.aspx.cs).

If there's a use case that isn't in the samples and you'd like to have added, feel free to open an issue on GitHub with a description of the use case or send a pull request, and I'd be more than happy to get it added. :)

Answer (score 0):

As per the latest version of REST API here are the details

Doc Link: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.payouts-batch/v1/#payouts_post

REST API [POST]: https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payouts

Body:

```
{
  "sender_batch_header": {
    "sender_batch_id": "Payouts_2018_100007",
    "email_subject": "You have a payout!",
    "email_message": "You have received a payout! Thanks for using our service!"
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "recipient_type": "EMAIL",
      "amount": {
        "value": "9.87",
        "currency": "USD"
      },
      "note": "Thanks for your patronage!",
      "sender_item_id": "201403140001",
      "receiver": "receiver@example.com",
      "alternate_notification_method": {
        "phone": {
          "country_code": "91",
          "national_number": "9999988888"
        }
      },
      "notification_language": "fr-FR"
    }
  ]
}
```

Sample response:

```
{
  "batch_header": {
    "sender_batch_header": {
      "sender_batch_id": "Payouts_2018_100008",
      "email_subject": "You have a payout!",
      "email_message": "You have received a payout! Thanks for using our service!"
    },
    "payout_batch_id": "5UXD2E8A7EBQJ",
    "batch_status": "PENDING"
  }
}
```