# Crossing PayPal APIs

Tags: paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal

I am working on a PayPal integration solution whereby the client application+server need to make use of features in several APIs, Adaptive Accounts (specifically "AddPaymentCard"), Adaptive Payments (specifically "Chained Payments") and Merchant APIs.

Is it possible to use those APIs together?

For example, can I

1. Add one or more credit cards as the funding source(s) using "AddPaymentCard" Adaptive Accounts API. *(client application)*
2. Choose **one** of the credit cards as the "funding source" for "Pay" Adaptive Payments operation. *(client application)*
3. Then, after the fact, use Merchant API to do operations on transactions created in step 2, eg. Void (DoVoid). *(server)*

**Let me elaborate on 3 here.**
With payment created by Adaptive Payment's "Pay" operation, can I then void the transaction with the Merchant API?
eg.

```
devtools-paypal.com/apiexplorer/AdaptivePayments, PAY operation
actionType PAY
currencyCode USD
…
receiverList
   receiver
      amount 1.00
      email     testuser@hotmail.com

Response
{
    "responseEnvelope": {
        "timestamp": "2014-08-24T09:36:47.259-07:00",
        "ack": "Success",
        "correlationId": "5ffaa01a860d1",
        "build": "12382931"
    },
    "payKey": "AP-3N46701432081335J",
    "paymentExecStatus": "CREATED"
}
```

Then, perform the transaction with

`www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=AP-3N46701432081335J.`

Then, can I perform a DoVoid operation (devtools-paypal.com/apiexplorer/PayPalAPIs) on the resulting transaction?

If 1+2 above is not possible, can I use REST API together with Adaptive Payments?

1. Store credit card using developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#store-a-credit-card
2. Somehow create an order of "Adaptive Payments, Chained" with  developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#create-an-order

Thanks!

Comment: After some digging, I think I found my answer to my second question. It's not yet possible to do adaptive payment with REST API. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15405632/paypal-rest-api-adaptive-multiple-payments-change-payee

Comment: @Lior I added more detail for "3" to show what I mean by "crossing".

Answer (score 0):

No.  DoVoid is only good for Authorizations.  The Pay API doesn't do authorizations, but rather it would do Preapprovals if you're using it that way.  If you are working that way, though, you can use the Preapproval API's to manage those profiles accordingly.

Again though, DoVoid would only come into play when voiding authorizations processed via DoAuthorization, Express Checkout, or Payments Pro, which are all part of the "classic API".

Comment: Ah alright, that's what I suspected too.
The Preapprovals in `developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Preapproval_API_Operation/` are closer to our need but the expiry limit on payKeyDuration doesn't quite work with us. Neither does the web redirect that it requires in the workflow.

Comment: You could use Express Checkout and/or Payments Pro with Reference Transactions then.